# How to compare two values in MVC validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, properties

I am creating an application where I am having Age range, weight range, height range and etc. So in these fields I am using two text boxes for each. For example for Age range I am using Age From and Age To these two textboxes and so on for the other properties. But I am trying to find a solution to compare the Age From and Age To to check whether the Age To is not getting bigger than the Age From and vice versa. To achieve this I have downloaded Foolproof from NUGET and doing like this:

```
    [GreaterThan("WeightFrom",ErrorMessage="Please verify the Weight Range")]
    public string WeightTo { get; set; }
```

But this Validator checks for the field as a required field whether it is not. Because it is possible that user may not fill this criteria at all but if they fill then I need to check the input to ensure that the Weight To is greater than the Weight From value. So, please advise me how do I achieve this.Is there any other way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Not clear what your asking - The attribute your using ensures that `WeightTo` is greater than the value of `WeightFrom` which seems to be what you want, but making the properties typeof `string` makes no sense - they would need to be a numeric type e.g. `int`

Comment: making it as string still doing the same thing but if I leave this Weight range blank then it is still making it RED to fill. But the system criteria is optional for these range fields.

Comment: Then you will need to wright you own validation attribute (say) `[GreaterThanIf]`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I am new in MVC so I would appreciate most if you could provide me a sample of creating the Validation Attribute.

Comment: Start with [this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) which is a good guide to creating validation attributes including both server side and client side validation. If your having problems, post the code you have tried indicating whats not working

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "WeightTo" property datatype as int, then you can use data annotation as [Range(0, 100)] to weight range.

Comment: No the range is fine but problem is that if I do not enter any value into the Wight range textbox then it is asking me to fill it. But the requirement is not that. Requirment is if user fill this Weight From and Weight TO textbox then I have to check whether Weight TO is greater thant Weight From or not.

Comment: @barsan, have you tried making the datatypes nullable; `int?`?

Comment: I have tried as per your suggestion just now but still not working.

Comment: What type of error you got? Check whether you script folder is having jquery.validate.unobtrusive,jquery.validate,jquery.unobtrusive-ajax. And have you put correct path to refer scrip files? Because these are client side validation. So javascript should be needed.

Answer (score 0):

In your post method, do your check there and use nullable ints for WeightTo and WeightFrom. I have created a DotNetFiddle for you here https://dotnetfiddle.net/ci0V2I

Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new SampleModel());
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SampleModel model)
    {       
        if(model.WeightFrom.HasValue && model.WeightTo.HasValue)
        {
            if(model.WeightFrom.Value < model.WeightTo.Value)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Weight from most be smaller than Weight to. Please fix this error."); 
            }
        }

        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model); 
        }

        return View(new SampleModel());
    }
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class SampleModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Weight Form")]
        public int? WeightFrom { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Weight To")]
        public int? WeightTo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.SampleModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}


                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {

                @Html.ValidationSummary()

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.WeightFrom)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WeightFrom, new {@class="form-control"}) 
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.WeightFrom)
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.WeightTo)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WeightTo, new {@class="form-control"}) 
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.WeightTo)
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new {@class="form-control"}) 
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit">Save</button>
                }
```